# MongoDB with Node.JS: editing the package.json file to install mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm following this tutorial http://blog.ijasoneverett.com/2013/03/a-sample-app-with-node-js-express-and-mongodb-part-1/

I changed the package.json file to include "mongodb": ">= 0.9.6-7"

My mongoDB is version 2.4.6

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a basic syntax error in package.json, like the error message clearly states. Just look closely and fix it (probably a missing comma) or at least post the file so we can tell you where the syntax error is.

Comment: I added a screen shot of my packages.json file. Hopefully we can get this solved.

Comment: See those 2 junk letters at the start of the file?

Comment: Zeus, you should probably accept @Peter's answer and upvote him.